# iOS UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

this thing is piss*ng me off for 5 days now.
I have my `UITableView` which is being filled from `NSMutableDictionary` that contains data pulled from Internet. Everything works just perfectly.

I have function that checks for new data which is actually `[NSURLRequest sendAsynchronousRequest...]` that returns some data if there is something new. I carefully crafted that when useful data is there, I add that data to my dictionary and `[self.tableView reloadData];` to display that. It's being displayed BUT, here is the problem.
Under my tableView is textField and a button that allows user to send a message. When user taps to text field, keyboard appears (normally) and I animate that textField move to "up", button move to "up" and tableView height to be visible with keyboard on. That also works fine, if I press return on keyboard, keyboard resigns, everything animates back down and that's it.

Problem is, if my keyboard is on, and everything is moved to up and i `reloadData`, all views reset and that means, tableView goes back down to it's full height, button goes back down, textField goes back down but keyboard stays... WHY? Why is view reseting it self?

I also tried using `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths...]` thinking that won't make that effect but it does the same thing. Why are `reloadData` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` (which are working great their job of inserting new data) messing up with my view?

Also if I print:

```
NSLog(@"Size Before: %f", self.tableView.frame.size.height);
[messages setObject:[newMessages objectForKey:key] forKey:date];
messagesKeys = [messages allKeys];
NSIndexPath *oNewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[messagesKeys count] - 1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oNewIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
NSLog(@"Size After: %f", self.tableView.frame.size.height);
```

size of my table view before and after the update, it shows same, shrinked size that should be but that's not the case. TableView, button and textField are being reseted and look like in storyboard...

Comment: This could be due to auto layout. If you directly change the frame of your UI elements, the they will revert to the frames defined by their constraints when any action that causes the view to redraw happens. You either need to turn off auto layout, or do your resizing and moving by adjusting constraints rather than setting frames.

Comment: This is something I wasn't thinking off. I will try this right away!

Comment: Maaan, you are my hero! AutoLayout was doing this! Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a BOOL variable, let's call it `isEditing` to your UIViewController, which will be set to YES in
`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method. If it becomes necessary to reload the data in the meantime (although this seems like bad design to me), just add

```
if (isEditing) {
  [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
  isEditing = NO;
}
```

This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. (quoted from documentation).
So basically, what I would do is something like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    isEditing = YES;
}

-(void) reloadData {
   //reload data
    if (isEditing) {
      [self.view endEditing:YES]; //or alternatively: [myTextField resignFirstResponder]
      isEditing = NO;
    }
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    isEditing = NO;
}
```

[EDIT] Regarding your *why* part:
*Dismissing the Keyboard
Although it typically displays the keyboard automatically, the system does not dismiss the keyboard automatically. Instead, it is your app’s responsibility to dismiss the keyboard at the appropriate time.*

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not having problem with dismissing keyboard, I'm in control of that, I'm just having problem with everything being redrawn to default when tableView is updated... Currently I'm doing that, when tableView reloads, keyboard dismiss and everything looks normal, I'm just bugging user with that keyboard dismiss...

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your tableView offscreen by setting its frame.y to a negative value rather than shrinking the tableView. You will not have to deal with height this way

Comment: Not sure how would this help since everything in view is being reseted to default frames, not only tableView.
Thanks anyway.